# React JS/Webpack/Sass/Bootstrap 4 anchor link cannot be centered?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, webpack

I am new to React JS and Webpack and have run into a really weird error.  I just want to center a anchor link on the screen.  Thats all!  However even if I inspect the element and remove all inherited styles and use the tried and true, set a width, margin auto method it will not move.  Not sure if this is a react/webpack thing I am just straight up missing.

[image]

Below is the anchor link component. And its classes SASS.  (Yes its parent has width: 100%)

```
render() {
    return (
      <a href={this.strava.oauth.getRequestAccessURL()}
        className="connect-strava-btn">
        Connect With Strava
      </a>
    );
  }
```

sass:

```
.connect-strava-btn{

  width: 250px;
  margin: auto;

  color: black;
  font-size: 11px;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Interestingly if you change the a to `<a>` to a `<p>` it then centers correctly.  What is it about that anchor link that react/webpack dosen't like?  Below is my webpack.config.js.  Help!

```
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/scripts/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel'
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json'
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './'
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is related to Webpack or React. Try adding

```
.connect-strava-btn{
  display: block;
}
```

to your CSS. Unless the element is a block, `margin: auto;` will have no effect.

[**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/IplrBl5TEO6ZWYP5p3C9?p=preview)